# Making entered commands bold at the prompt

Tags: linux, terminal, command-prompt, bash

This is my current PS1 prompt definition from by .bashrc:

```
PS1='\[\033[01;33m\]★ \[\033[01;30m\]\w \[\033[32m\]\$ \[\033[m\]'
```

My command prompt works great and I love it, but I would like to add one more little thing. I would really like to be able to have the text I enter (commands at the prompt) **bold**.

I know I could change the last escape code to be:

```
\[\033[01m\]
```

Which would make the command prompt text I enter bold, but it also does funny (undesirable) things with the output of entered commands.

**Is there a way to do this? If so, how?**

I am running gnome-terminal in Ubuntu.

Comment: If there is already an answer in bash, then this is probably a Super User questions. The answer may involve hacking bash, which would be a Stack Overflow topic.

Comment: I'm not sure which it would be. I haven't been able to find anything yet. Would it be a good idea to post it there too?

Comment: "...but it also does funny (undesirable) things with the output of entered commands...". Some applications set colors on their own, like `ls`. You can't really avoid that.

Comment: No. Don't double post. If a quorum of high rep users decides this is better on Super User, they fan migrate it there. I'm "high rep" for that purpose, but am holding my vote for now...

Comment: @dmckee: Good to know. I had no idea that was the way it worked. I will wait patiently for a decision or answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was looking to do this too. I found an answer here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt#Different_colors_for_text_entry_and_console_output

Add this line to your ~/.bashrc which will reset the color that you set in your PS1 variable before displaying your command's output:

trap 'echo -ne "\e[0m"' DEBUG